# How can I combine two macros to initialize an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, macros

I'm working with two macros in C and would like to combine them to initialize an array of strings. Here are the macros in question:

```cpp
#define FOREACH_T(ACTION) \
ACTION("T1", 1) \
ACTION("T2", 2) \
ACTION("T3", 3) 

#define FOREACH_K(ACTION) \
ACTION("K1", 17) \
ACTION("K2", 20) \
ACTION("K3", 23)
```

My goal is to combine these macros in such a way as to obtain a value array such that, for example, the element at index `[1 + 17]` is `"T1_K1"`.

I'm a bit at a loss as to how to combine these macros to achieve the desired result. I'd like to get something like this:

```cpp
const char* value[] = { [1 + 17] = "T1_K1", [1 + 20] = "T1_K2", [1 + 23] = "T1_K3",
                        [2 + 17] = "T2_K1", [2 + 20] = "T2_K2", [2 + 23] = "T2_K3",
                        [3 + 17] = "T3_K1", [3 + 20] = "T3_K2", [3 + 23] = "T3_K3"};
};
```

Comment: I can't think of a good method right now, it _might_ be possible to achieve this via X Macros... but you're approaching the point where you'd probably be better off writing a code generator in a "real" programming language instead of trying to achieve the effect with macros.

Comment: You are asking for how to interleave contents of 2 completely separate macros. If there is way to do that (which is suspect), it is likely a solution which will result in extremely complex and unreadable mess. So there is no reasonable way to do it with your existing macros. It will be easier if you merge all of your data in single macro (like `FOREACH_TK`), and base all your code generation on that.

Comment: @Cubic That's what I thought, but I wondered if I was missing something. Thanks

Comment: @SupportUkraine Yes sorry, I edited

Comment: @user694733 I'd like to be able to do this so I can have my macros defined in separate places without having to mix everything up. I knew it was complicated, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing out on a classic technique with macros that makes it possible.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  I think you need to explain the real problem ypu are trying to solve

Comment: @SupportUkraine This is just an example with random values to show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @SupportUkraine It was to create an example that would be very easy to understand and I didn't think of that detail. I'll keep your comment in mind for next time. Thank you

Comment: @Cubic These _are_ X macros... just named ACTION instead of X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change the list macros, then it's simple. Doing it without changing the macros should also be possible, but harder.

```
#define FOREACH_T(ACTION, ...) \
    ACTION("T1", 1, __VA_ARGS__) \
    ACTION("T2", 2, __VA_ARGS__) \
    ACTION("T3", 3, __VA_ARGS__) 

#define FOREACH_K(ACTION, ...) \
    ACTION("K1", 17, __VA_ARGS__) \
    ACTION("K2", 18, __VA_ARGS__) \
    ACTION("K3", 19, __VA_ARGS__) 

#define FOO(s, x, s2, x2) [x + x2] = s "_" s2,
#define FOO2(s, x, ...) FOREACH_T(FOO, s, x)

const char* value[] = {
    FOREACH_K(FOO2,)
};
```

Note that this emits `warning: initializer overrides prior initialization of this subobject`, because e.g. `1+18 == 2+17`, and so on.

---

Here's the same thing without changing the macro. This uses [`macro_sequence_for`](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for/), a library I made for writing preprocessor loops that would otherwise be too tricky.

Note that with this, you might as well simplify the macros to lists like `("T1",1)("T2",2)("T3",3)`, no need to accept another macro as the argument. This solution ends up converting the lists to this form first.

<kbd>[run on gcc.godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:20,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:20,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:20,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:20,startLineNumber:10),source:%27%23include+%3Chttps://raw.githubusercontent.com/HolyBlackCat/macro_sequence_for/master/include/macro_sequence_for.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+FOREACH_T(ACTION)+%5C%0A++++ACTION(%22T1%22,+1)+%5C%0A++++ACTION(%22T2%22,+2)+%5C%0A++++ACTION(%22T3%22,+3)%0A%0A%23define+FOREACH_K(ACTION)+%5C%0A++++ACTION(%22K1%22,+17)+%5C%0A++++ACTION(%22K2%22,+18)+%5C%0A++++ACTION(%22K3%22,+19)%0A%0A%23define+IDENTITY(...)+__VA_ARGS__%0A%23define+PARENS(...)+(__VA_ARGS__)%0A%0A%23define+BODY(n,+d,+name,+value)+BODY2(IDENTITY+d,+name,+value)%0A%23define+BODY2(...)+BODY3(__VA_ARGS__)%0A%23define+BODY3(name1,+value1,+name2,+value2)+%5Bvalue1+%2B+value2%5D+%3D+name1+%22_%22+name2,%0A%0A%23define+OUTER_BODY(n,+d,+name,+value)+SF_FOR_EACH0(BODY,+SF_STATE,+SF_NULL,+(name,+value),+FOREACH_K(PARENS))%0A%0Aconst+char+*value%5B%5D+%3D+%7B%0A++++SF_FOR_EACH(OUTER_BODY,+SF_NULL,+SF_NULL,,+FOREACH_T(PARENS))%0A%7D%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1701,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc17+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:25,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+17.0.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:35.94059405940594,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:pp,i:(clang-format:%270%27,editorid:1,filter-headers:%270%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,treeid:0),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Preprocessor+Output+x86-64+clang+17.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),l:%274%27,m:39.05940594059406,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)</kbd>

```
#include <macro_sequence_for.h>

#define FOREACH_T(ACTION) \
    ACTION("T1", 1) \
    ACTION("T2", 2) \
    ACTION("T3", 3)

#define FOREACH_K(ACTION) \
    ACTION("K1", 17) \
    ACTION("K2", 18) \
    ACTION("K3", 19)

#define IDENTITY(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define PARENS(...) (__VA_ARGS__)

#define BODY(n, d, name, value) BODY2(IDENTITY d, name, value)
#define BODY2(...) BODY3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define BODY3(name1, value1, name2, value2) [value1 + value2] = name1 "_" name2,

#define OUTER_BODY(n, d, name, value) SF_FOR_EACH0(BODY, SF_STATE, SF_NULL, (name, value), FOREACH_K(PARENS))

const char *value[] = {
    SF_FOR_EACH(OUTER_BODY, SF_NULL, SF_NULL,, FOREACH_T(PARENS))
};
```

Comment: @SupportUkraine I assume this is just a typo in the question, and the actual numbers are picked to not have overlaps.

Comment: Thank you, I would have liked not to have to change the macros, but according to all the replies, I'll have to do otherwise. At least I'm learning the limits of macros to keep the code "clean".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, it was just to illustrate what I wanted to do.

Comment: @antho I've added a version that keeps the original macro syntax. It's not that bad.